# Adding new column to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to add new column to existing datagridview so:

```
DataColumn col = new DataColumn(( dataGridView1.ColumnCount+1).ToString());
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

But it doesn't work.. how to do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is so easy..

```
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column","Test");
```

Answer (score 9):

I think that you need to specify what type of cell the column will contain.

For example:

```
DataGridViewColumn  newCol = new DataGridViewColumn(); // add a column to the grid
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
newCol.CellTemplate = cell;

newCol.HeaderText = "test2";
newCol.Name = "test2";
newCol.Visible = true;
newCol.Width = 40;

gridColors.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

Comment: `DataGridViewCell` is **abstract,** now.   
Use  
`DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();`  
for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple, in just one line code

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColumnName, HeaderText);
```