# c# backgroundworker creating datagridview and creating columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

I am getting this error "No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first." what am i doing wrong here?

```
        //create datagridview1
          DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

         // DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

          // Initialize the DataGridView.
          dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
          dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

          DataGridViewColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
          column1.DataPropertyName = "Column1";
          column1.Name = "title";
          dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);

          DataGridViewColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
          column2.DataPropertyName = "Column2";
          column2.Name = "imageurl";
          dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);

          DataGridViewColumn column3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
          column3.DataPropertyName = "Column3";
          column3.Name = "videourl";
          dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);

          DataGridViewColumn column4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
          column4.DataPropertyName = "Column4";
          column4.Name = "done";
          dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column4);
```

Comment: that code is directly underneath private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(title, "image", "videourl", "no");

Comment: @mxadam Show the code that invokes `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`. It looks like a synchronization issue, could be that your thread is running before you add columns to your DataGrdiView.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column","Test");
```

or if you want to choose coulmn  type

```
DataGridViewColumn  newCol = new DataGridViewColumn(); // add a column to the grid
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
newCol.CellTemplate = cell;

newCol.HeaderText = "test2";
newCol.Name = "test2";
newCol.Visible = true;
newCol.Width = 40;

gridColors.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582661/adding-new-column-to-datagridview)

You also can see [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @mxadam, strange. I verify it and it's work to me. Pay attention: `Add` function receivce 2 parameters. one is column name and the second is the header.